# What is "Expectation over $Y$" in the Law of Total Expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am struggling with the Law of Total Expectation, in the part of "expectation over $Y$".

In [the lecture note](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Efewster/325/notes/ch3.pdf), page 55, the Law of Total Expectation is stated as

> $\mathbb E(X) = \mathbb E_Y\big(\mathbb E(X|Y)\big)$; where $\mathbb E_Y$ denotes expectation over $Y$.

My questions are:

1. What does the subscript $Y$ in $\mathbb E_Y$ mean?
2. Why in some other documents, they just simply write the law as $\mathbb E(X)=\mathbb E\big(\mathbb E(X|Y)\big)$ [(without the subscript Y, for example in another lecture note, page 3)](http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/%7Efarhadi/ASPER/Law%20of%20Total%20Variance.pdf)? So, does it really matter to keep the subscript $Y$ or just an option for a more clarified?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hello! $E_Y$ means that you are taking the expectation value over different possibilities of $Y$, and not of $X$. So you keep $X$ fixed (as in the LHS of the equation), and take the weighted sum $\sum_Y P(XY)v(XY)$ ($P$ for probability, $v$ for value). I would almost say this is clear from the context because you have a fixed $X$ on the left hand side, so I would probably leave it, but it certainly doesn't hurt, so...

Comment: It's also redundant.  $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$ is a function only of $Y$ so fixing everything but $Y$ does nothing. $$\mathsf E_Y(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))$$

Comment: Yes, you can ignore the subscript $Y$.  It is only there to be a "helpful" reminder of what is random.  Since taking expectations of something makes sense when that thing is random, you can ask "well what part of it is random?" The subscript $Y$ is just to remind you that $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable that inherits its randomness from $Y$.

Comment: It's more clear to me now. Thank you all for your help!